# Pagination in SAS based software

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, pagination

I am developing a SAS based system using jsp, servlet and java. And i am confused in using client side pagination(getting all result at one go) or using server side(With every click).

If i use client side pagination how much data is o.k. And what is the best way to implement pagination like javascript, ajax, jquery etc.

Answer (score 2):

I reckon js/jquery based pagination with Ajax for data fetch is great. You need to consider if you need sorting or not. I implemented jQuery based pagination 7 months back, and that time the pagination almost become really slow (1000 rows 10 rows per page) because of too much data. So, please make sure you implement Ajax based pagination.

I used this: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

and this: http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html

Also, antoher helpful link:
http://www.xarg.org/2011/09/jquery-pagination-revised/

P.S. - Be very careful about syntax and classes for pagination implementation. One spelling mistake and you might get into circles.

Extra information: If you are thinking of using a different language, try using Ruby on Rails. You can use `will_paginate` or Kaminari gem for simple implementation of pagination.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends upon volume of your data and the probability of user loading that page in his session. 
If the dataset is limited to say max 100* rows or so, and each record has few columns with small data size, you could go for client side pagination. But if the max of dataset is unknown or its gonna grow gradually, its  best to go for a server side pagination. 
Ajax with jQuery is definitely the way to go. Every jQuery grid plugin has its own mechanism for pagination but the basic logic is similar :

1. You need to design your backend APIs such that they accept
   `maxResults` and `currentPage` as params, along with other params.
2. The API which interacts with your DB fetches maximum `maxResults` no. of rows and the first row starts from `(currentPage -1) * pageSize`

I have been using [jQgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) and found it very well documented and simple to implement.
Helpful post : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations

NB: *100 is just an example don't talke it literally :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd certainly look at a combination of server side pagination and client side pagination. 
There is no sense in returning 1000 (or 10000+) rows of data, if all you are going to do is display 10 at a time.

If you are going to be displaying data in a grid, then I'd suggest you look at [Datatables.net](http://datatables.net). They have some great [examples](http://datatables.net/examples/) including [pagination](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html) and [pipelining your data from the server](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/pipeline.html) (ie. returning a few more records than you actually display so you have fewer calls to retrieve more data).